# Simple Banking Application in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I hope that someone can point me in the right direction, as I am new to programming.

I made a basic banking application. It displays a balance for the account, has a textbox for the user to enter the amount, and 2 buttons: one for depositing an amount into the account and one for withdrawing an amount. If the user tries to deposit or withdraw a negative number or "0" then it gives an error that it isn't a valid amount. If the user tries to withdraw more than is in the account, it gives an error that they cannot withdraw more money than is in the account.

My problem is that all the error messages are working for the deposit button, but not for the withdraw button. I used nested If structure, output to a label at the bottom.

I tried using breakpoints to examine my variables, but didn't find any issues.

I don't really want the answer, just some help to understand why the Deposit button will give the error but the Withdraw button won't show either error.

```
Public Class Form1
    ' Prologue
    ' This is a simple banking application. 
    ' It displays a balance for the account, calculates deposits and withdraws, and gives errors for invalid amounts and overdraws

    ' Modular Declarations
    Dim mdecBalance As Decimal = 1000

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Output
        lblBalance.Text = mdecBalance.ToString("c")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDeposit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeposit.Click
        ' Declarations
        Dim decDeposit As Decimal
        Dim strDepProblem As String

        ' Input
        decDeposit = txtAmount.Text

        ' Processing
        If decDeposit > 0 Then
            mdecBalance = mdecBalance + decDeposit
        Else
            If decDeposit <= 0 Then
                strDepProblem = "That is not a valid amount to deposit"
            End If
        End If

        ' Output
        lblBalance.Text = mdecBalance.ToString("c")
        lblMessage.Text = strDepProblem

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnWithdraw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWithdraw.Click
        ' Declarations
        Dim decWithdraw As Decimal
        Dim strWithdrawNegative As String
        Dim strWithdrawMoreThan As String

        ' Input
        decWithdraw = txtAmount.Text

        ' Processing
        If decWithdraw > 0 Then
            mdecBalance = mdecBalance - decWithdraw
        Else
            If decWithdraw <= 0 Then
                strWithdrawNegative = "Cannot use 0 or negative numbers"
            Else
                If decWithdraw > mdecBalance Then
                    strWithdrawMoreThan = "Cannot withdraw more than you have"
                End If
            End If
        End If

        ' Output
        lblBalance.Text = mdecBalance.ToString("c")
        lblMessage.Text = strWithdrawNegative
        lblMessage.Text = strWithdrawMoreThan
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You check `If decWithdraw > mdecBalance Then` only when `decWithdraw <= 0`.

Comment: Also, note that `lblMessage.Text` is at first assigned to `strWithdrawNegative`, and then immediately assigned to `strWithdrawMoreThan` - that's probably not what you really want. Because, right now, `lblMessage.Text` will always have the value of `strWithdrawMoreThan` in it (the last assignment always wins).

Comment: @rskar how can I output a different message to the same label? I thought maybe I'd use the OR logical operator, but I need a different message to show in the same label so I don't think that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do too much in too complex a way. Write your functions so they have this pattern:

```
If something is no good Then
  Say it's no good
  Stop processing

If something else is no good Then
  Say this other thing is no good
  Stop processing

Now that you've checked every possible error condition, we're all good to go
Do the work
```

This means you write your code like:

```
     Private Sub btnDeposit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeposit.Click

        lblMessage.Text = "" 'be optimistic; nothing will go wrong

        Dim decDeposit = Convert.ToDecimal(txtAmount.Text) 'be explicit when converting data. Turn on Option Strict and Option Explicit


        If decDeposit = 0 Then
          lblMessage.Text = "Cannot deposit 0"
          Return 'stop processing
        End If

        If decDeposit < 0 Then
          errorLabel.Text = "Cannot deposit negative"
          Return 'stop processing
        End If

        mdecBalance = mdecBalance + decDeposit


        lblBalance.Text = mdecBalance.ToString("c")
        lblMessage.Text = "Deposit ok"

    End Sub
```

If you're having multiple nested If If If .. you're headed for trouble. This simplified workflow of checking and making sure everything is OK right at the start and only proceeding if it is is generally a simpler way to work.

If you want to tell the user every mistake they made all in one go, you can work like this:

```
    lblMessage.Text = ""

    If testForBad1 Then lblMessage.Text &= "Bad thing 1 happened"

    If testForBad2 Then lblMessage.Text &= "Bad thing 2 happened"

    If testForBad3 Then lblMessage.Text &= "Bad thing 3 happened"

    If lblMessage.Text <> "" Then Return 'any errors will put a text
```

We still have only one nest level here; very simple and easy to follow code

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas to think on, focusing on `Sub btnWithdraw_Click`.

The code you have under the comment `' Processing` is known as an "If-Else Ladder" (http://www.eng.fsu.edu/~haik/met.dir/hcpp.dir/notes.dir/cppnotes/node41.html). To make that ladder with better clarity, it can be refactored to:

```
' Processing
If decWithdraw > 0 Then
    mdecBalance = mdecBalance - decWithdraw
ElseIf decWithdraw <= 0 Then
    strWithdrawNegative = "Cannot use 0 or negative numbers"
ElseIf decWithdraw > mdecBalance Then
    strWithdrawMoreThan = "Cannot withdraw more than you have"
End If
```

Since that above ladder puts particular focus on `decWithdraw`, it can be refactored to use `Select Case`:

```
' Processing
Select Case decWithdraw
    Case Is > 0
        mdecBalance = mdecBalance - decWithdraw
    Case Is <= 0
        strWithdrawNegative = "Cannot use 0 or negative numbers"
    Case Is < mdecBalance ' I.e. decWithdraw > mdecBalance
        strWithdrawMoreThan = "Cannot withdraw more than you have"
End Select
```

Note that VB.NET has the `-=` assignment statement; so `mdecBalance = mdecBalance - decWithdraw` can be refactored to `mdecBalance -= decWithdraw`.

Note that the code tests `decWithdraw > 0` before testing `decWithdraw > mdecBalance`. That's a logic error - the account can get overdrawn (without the desired error) because the `decWithdraw > mdecBalance` test will not get done because, after the `decWithdraw > 0` test succeeds, the code will flow around it.

In fixing that bug, it's makes better sense to return to "If-Else":

```
' Processing
If Not decWithdraw > 0 Then
    strWithdrawNegative = "Cannot use 0 or negative numbers"
ElseIf Not decWithdraw <= mdecBalance Then
    strWithdrawMoreThan = "Cannot withdraw more than you have"
Else
    mdecBalance -= decWithdraw
End If
```

Note how the tests are ordered now. First, we make sure `decWithdraw` is generally valid (must be > 0), then we make sure `decWithdraw` is valid for the more specific situation (must be <= `mdecBalance`).

If your sense of math is good, the above can also be written as:

```
' Processing
If decWithdraw <= 0 Then
    strWithdrawNegative = "Cannot use 0 or negative numbers"
ElseIf decWithdraw > mdecBalance Then
    strWithdrawMoreThan = "Cannot withdraw more than you have"
Else
    mdecBalance -= decWithdraw
End If
```

E.g. mathematically speaking `decWithdraw <= 0` is the same test as `Not decWithdraw > 0`. Part of the art of programming is in the style; one needs to find a way to write the code which fosters clarity for the humans who may need to read and understand it someday, balanced with how it affects computer performance. (https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) I'm sticking with `Not decWithdraw > 0` because I think it'll be an easier read for an audience of corporate line-of-business programmers and business analysts.

Anyway, the style you went with in the error reporting is awkward. If we were to persist with it, one way one can get the right message to come through is:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strWithdrawNegative) Then
    lblMessage.Text = strWithdrawNegative
ElseIf Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strWithdrawMoreThan) Then
    lblMessage.Text = strWithdrawMoreThan 
Else
    lblMessage.Text = Nothing
End If
```

It's ugly, but it will work. I would not do the error reporting like this myself. Another style, which scales better, could be:

```
Sub btnWithdraw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWithdraw.Click

    Const ValidationError_WithdrawNegative As Integer = 1
    Const ValidationError_WithdrawMoreThan As Integer = 2

    ' Declarations
    Dim decWithdraw As Decimal
    Dim intValidationErrorCode As Integer = 0
    Dim strValidationErrorMessage As String = Nothing

    ' Input
    decWithdraw = txtAmount.Text

    ' Processing
    If Not decWithdraw > 0 Then
        intValidationErrorCode = ValidationError_WithdrawNegative
        strValidationErrorMessage = "Cannot use 0 or negative numbers"
    ElseIf Not decWithdraw <= mdecBalance Then
        intValidationErrorCode = ValidationError_WithdrawMoreThan
        strValidationErrorMessage = "Cannot withdraw more than you have"
    Else
        mdecBalance -= decWithdraw
    End If

    ' Output
    lblBalance.Text = mdecBalance.ToString("c")
    lblMessage.Text = If(intValidationErrorCode > 0,
        strValidationErrorMessage,
        Nothing)

End Sub
```

`intValidationErrorCode`, when > 0, signals the error; `ValidationError_WithdrawNegative` and `ValidationError_WithdrawMoreThan` indicates the specific error. (These constants are defined, because it is best to avoid "magic numbers" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming) ).

Note that `decWithdraw = txtAmount.Text` can error at run-time if something other than a valid number is in `txtAmount.Text`. One should check for that too:

```
Sub btnWithdraw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 'Handles btnWithdraw.Click

    Const ValidationError_NotNumeric As Integer = 1
    Const ValidationError_WithdrawNegative As Integer = 2
    Const ValidationError_WithdrawMoreThan As Integer = 3

    ' Declarations
    Dim decWithdraw As Decimal
    Dim intValidationErrorCode As Integer = 0
    Dim strValidationErrorMessage As String = Nothing

    ' Input
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, decWithdraw) Then       
        intValidationErrorCode = ValidationError_NotNumeric
        strValidationErrorMessage = "Entry for withdraw is not a valid number"
    Else

        ' Processing
        If Not decWithdraw > 0 Then
            intValidationErrorCode = ValidationError_WithdrawNegative
            strValidationErrorMessage = "Cannot use 0 or negative numbers"
        ElseIf Not decWithdraw <= mdecBalance Then
            intValidationErrorCode = ValidationError_WithdrawMoreThan
            strValidationErrorMessage = "Cannot withdraw more than you have"
        Else
            mdecBalance -= decWithdraw
        End If

    End If

    ' Output
    lblBalance.Text = mdecBalance.ToString("c")
    lblMessage.Text = If(intValidationErrorCode > 0,
        strValidationErrorMessage,
        Nothing)

End Sub
```

The above is not the only way to go about it, and perhaps not the very best way, but hopefully it's a start. Perhaps you can try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, using tag "beginner" for further advice.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I appreciate your help. I read up on that url you posted and it helped me to understand what I was doing wrong and better and more efficient way to write it in the future. I will post with "beginner" in the future as well. Thank you again!